# What things required to host a website at home

Tags: web-development, web-hosting, server, ip-address

I have a Linux server runing Ubuntu.  On it I've installed PHP, Mysql, and Apache.
I need to host a site on my server having static IP, but I don't have any experience in web hosting.
Can you please tell me that what are the things are required to host a site?  I suspect I need web space and an IP address.

Can you please also tell me which is the best hosting plans available in UK market for a beginner?

I read somewhere **if we are using non-fixed IP it takes 24 hrs to change DNS**  is this correct?

Comment: To answer the question you've asked twice in comments regarding a permanent IP address: This may be available from your ISP, probably for an extra fee. This is commonly called a `Static IP`. If you're doing this for business, though, you probably want to get something other than a standard residential connection, because dynamic IPs aren't the only reason not to host out of your home.

Comment: @Harry: are you doing this for fun or because you want to become a webhoster? In this last case it's cool, instead of just becoming the nth reseller of the (n-1)th reseller of the (n-2)th reseller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a regular internet connection at home (cable,ADSL, etc.) you won't have a permanent IP address, so you'll need some kind of [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service (to forward incoming requests to your server). This means you'll have to install some kind of software to notify the Dynamic DNS service your IP address has changed, note that this could be on your server or at your router as many home routers (lynksys,dlink,etc.) already have this feature.

Comment: Thanks t3mujin, yes i have internet correction, not having permanent IP. I think on my server or router don't have that feature. Do you have any idea which software i have to install to notify IP address

Comment: Can i buy Permanent IP ?

Comment: Here's a reference for dynamic dns update clients: http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/

Comment: You could buy a static IP from your service provider, but usually that's a bit expensive, so for now I think you should stick to dynamic DNS. The software you have to install is a small daemon that notifies the dynamic dns provider your IP has changed, usually each provider has its own software (user360 pointed the dyndns.com) and you should find instructions on each service on how you should install it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dyanmic dns service to cover the non-fixed IP thing like this one...

http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/

A couple of things to be aware of though...

1) If you're hosting from home, you'll have to configure your router/firewall to allow the traffic in as well. There are security implications with doing this, so if it's a desktop you're running this on and have other files on it, you may be putting this computer at risk. IF this computer connects with others inside your network, they could be at risk as well. Typically web servers go in a "DMZ" with firewalling on both sides (the side facing the internet, and the side facing your internal network).

2) If you're using a typical DSL/Cable connection traffic speeds for download are typically a lot faster than upload. Also, you may have as part of your TOS a clause that you CANNOT host a server. That's common here in the US anyhow.

Hope that helps. If you're just doing this for fun, I'd give it a go. If you're looking to host others' sites as part of a business, I'd be careful of what you're getting into. You could probably get a hosting package and host others' domains as sub-domains of your site a lot easier.

D.

Comment: Thanks Don, its very much helpful. At present i am doing this to learn hosting process.

Comment: In future i need for buisness too, Can i buy Permanent IP ?

Comment: The TOS issue is very relevant, I think we don't have such a thing here in Europe

Comment: In the Netherlands we will soon have fiber in every home where servers are allowed and even encouraged e.g. 200mbit at http://www.xmsnet.nl/pakketten/internet is where i am.

Comment: @Harry - if you get a fixed IP later I think you could just eliminate the dyndns part if you wanted to. You'd have to run your own DNS/nameserver setup locally I believe. I have never done that, so I can't speak for sure.