# How to serve WAMP website over internet?

Tags: apache, wampserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it feasible to run a public-facing website from my home network?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16723/is-it-feasible-to-run-a-public-facing-website-from-my-home-network)

I have just installed a portable WAMP (EasyPHP) in order to test a website.

I can access the site via localhost but when I enter my public IP in a browser I get the "Welcome to Apache" type of page.

What is the quickest way to make the website accessible over the internet?

Comment: You will find plenty of solution on Google .. https://www.google.fr/search?q=localhost+accessible+over+internet

Comment: By the way, why do you cross-posted all your questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007893/how-to-serve-wamp-website-over-internet

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a dynamic IP you'll need to use a service such as http://www.no-ip.com/ which is a Dynamic DNS service. It'll keep track of your IP address updating it's DNS accordingly to route traffic to your local WAMP server when people type in your website address. So once you sign up with them or any other service go to whatismyip.com get your IP address and enter it along with the website to point it to. You'll probably have to update the name servers in the registrar to point to the DNS service provider.

You'll need to make sure port 80 is open some ISP's block this unless you have a higher class of service so check with them. Then login to your router and route port 80 to the local IP of the computer with WAMP installed on.

You can even have another computer on your network running WAMP and in the router just set the IP to route to.