# How to create a temporary staging server on my home machine

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What things required to host a website at home](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/what-things-required-to-host-a-website-at-home)

I want to create a temporary staging server which can be accessed (i.e. via browser) by other people that I want to show the website to (a business partner who is half way accross the world).

IIRC, my ISP issues dynamic addresses so I may need to register with a (DNS server?) - not sure about this. Although I'm a software developer, I don't know much about the hardware side of things - and would appreciate help in getting me setup so I can show a website to a business partner.

Here are the relevant details:

Web server: Apache 2.2
OS: Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS
modem/router: ZyXel P-600

Answer (score 0):

If you must use your home computer and it has a dynamic address, you need 2 things.

1. A stack , in your case you already have apache.
2. A DNS manager
3. A domain name

A Static DNS manager will point your domain name to whatever your IP is on the fly.

Some services ( just google this):
http://www.zoneedit.com/
http://www.dnsexit.com/
http://dyn.com/
http://www.no-ip.com/

The alternative is to get a static ISP for your host or do what everyone else does and use cloud/shared/vps/dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

you really did not supply enough details about YOUR internal network, but :
1. install a webserver - (XAMPP is my favorite) - but I guess you already have this .

1. register with [DYNDNS](http://dyn.com) (and read FAQ) - any other dynamic ip service can work (use google)
2. Open your ports to forwarding (read [portforward.com](http://www.portforward.com))
3. Depending on your ISP internal DNS system and IP assignment - this should be enough work as far as your internal network goes. I have done it myself several times.

However - it is better always to just find a websever and put it there ...

alternative - you can set up VPN (even free ones - google again) or ask a static IP (not cheap)