# Link Domains/Subdomains to folders in a PC Server?

Tags: server

My PC has a configuration to work as a server. It has quad core processor with 8GB RAM. 
So I made it a server.
Now i want to know, how can I link the domain names to various folders in my WAMP.
At present, when I am calling my IP address e.g. 123.234.345.456, I get index file from **C:/wamp/www/**.
But I want to forward e.g. **www.example.com** to folder **C:/wamp/www/example** and **test.example.com** to folder **C:/wamp/www/test**
Does anyone have idea how to do this?
And what should I do in my domain provider's controls, so that they can fetch data from my server, without changing URL.

Comment: You will have to edit your Apache config files -- you will need to use virtual hosts approach (which is not used by WAMP or alike by default). More details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/ ; http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Comment: That's regarding Apache. But you still will need to configure DNS so those domain names point to your server (unless all requests are done locally -- then you can use `hosts` file for that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What things required to host a website at home](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/what-things-required-to-host-a-website-at-home)

Comment: @LazyOne:
How can I get the DNS?
I just have my IP address, which shows result from a folder in my Windows XP Computer

Comment: The answer in the link provided by @paulmorriss will give enough info

Comment: @LazyOne: That answer is not even related to my question. I already have a static IP and working server, which I want to make for websites.
E.g. When I visit www.example.com, it will fetch data from my IP hosted (123.321.123.321) WAMP/www/example folder. And when I open test2.example.com, then data should come from WAMP/www/example/test folder.